# Memory leak in tkinter/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, memory-leaks, tkinter

My application contains large quantity of graphs displayed in a tkinter GUI. Because matplotlib is quite slow, I wanted to spend as little time as possible on updating graphs to display new data. Because all my graphs have the same dimensions and all data is normalized to [0, 1] and has 480 data points, I recycle a single figure and a single plot instance to save time.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, subplots_adjust

class DataFrame:
    def __init__(self, master, *args):
        self.root = Frame(master, ....)  # Main app interacts only with this widget
        ....
        self.graph_figure = figure(figsize=(3.75, .5), dpi=64)
        subplots_adjust(left=0, right=239/240, bottom=1/32, top=1)
        self.graph_plot = self.graph_figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.graph_plotdata,  = self.graph_plot.plot(list(range(480)), [f/480 for f in range(480)])
        self.graph_plot.set_xlim(0, 479)
        self.display_graphs = [Canvas(self.root) for _ in range(16)]
        for i in range(16):
            self.display_graphs[i].place(x=760+240*(i//4), y=32*(i % 4), width=240, height=32)

    def draw_graph(self, title, data):
        self.graph_figure.suptitle(title)
        self.graph_plotdata.set_ydata(data)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.graph_figure, master=self.root)
        return canvas.get_tk_widget()

    def rebuild_graph(self, data, index):
        self.display_graphs[index].destroy()
        self.display_graphs[index] = self.draw_graph(self.graph_names[index], data)
        self.display_graphs[index].place(x=760+240*(index//4), y=32*(index % 4), width=240, height=32)
```

I attempted to `del canvas` before returning the widget in the draw_graph method but it doesn't help. Eventually it crashes with `Fail to allocate bitmap` message. How can I cleanup old data explicitly?

---

**Edit**: After some inspecting the code, this seems to be purely tkinter's problem. It refuses to release the allocated memory to the system, nor does it reuse existing memory for new widgets when old ones are destroyed. Weirdly enough, I'm seeing a memory leak in this code:

```
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
while True:
    root.update()  # Fills up memory indefinitely
```